# How to set slider position when mouse click on it in an UWP app?

Tags: uwp

I want to use mouse click to re-position the slider, and now I know it is slider's internal feature. But which event is raised? 
Thanks!

Comment: I did not understand your question. What you described is the default behavior of the built-in [Slider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/slider) control.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT Thank you for your reply! You are right. I want to know which event is raised when using mouse click the slider to re-position it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> want to know which event is raised when using mouse click the slider to re-position it

The [ValueChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.rangebase.valuechanged) event will be fired.

You could register it and do some operations in its event handler.

```
<Slider ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged"></Slider>
```

```
private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
}
```